# Amazon S3:putObject is not updating

Tags: php, amazon-s3

`putObject` method is not updating my S3 bucket destination file but returning me with success message. I have also tried using exception handling and logging but no errors and not updating my repository.

```
try
{
   S3::putObject(S3::inputFile(<path>,flase),,destination path,S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array(), array('Content-Type' => 'application/javascript','Content-Encoding' => 'gzip'));`
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, It was due to caching and it stays in cache for 1 hr. SO purging cache was solution for my problem.